# Given a sample determine using Chi-squared test whether these values fit in an EXPONENTIAL distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Here I've got such a problem.

> I was given $n = 20$ values for time of good functioning of a robot
>   between two consecutive defects.
>
> *1200, 1432, 1502, 1100, 3286, 4235, 1149, 5236, 2234, 2115, 2025*
>
> I have to determine if these values fits in an exponential
>   distribution using ***chi-squared test***.

What I've done is:

1. I've created an interval large enough to comprise all these values;
2. I've divided this interval and then counted the frequency of appearance of values from the above sample between two consecutive limits. For example, taken an interval $[1000, 1500]$, the frequency of occurrences of the values from the sample in this interval, choosing 1200,1432,1100,1149 is 4.
3. I calculated $$\sum_{i = 1}\frac{(f_i - np_{i})^2}{np_{i}}$$ ***formula(1)***

!!! I used for calculating probability the punctual estimator for parameter of exponential distribution, using the formula:
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{\bar X}$$, where $\alpha$ is the parameter estimator and
$$\bar X = \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n}$$

The problem is: I've got a totally different value for formula (1) in comparison with the value of Hi-squared with n - 1 freedom grades and $\alpha = 0.1$, where n is the number of sub-intervals I divided the interval. I suppose it's too big.

It's obvious that the selection does not fit in exponential distribution The idea also is, I'm confused about how I should  properly solve this exercise. Can you, please, show me some kind of example of how can I exactly determine this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you suppose it's too big, did you actually compute the p-value of the test you're performing ?

Comment: I've computed the sum of all the values obtained from the formula 1.

Comment: Please edit your question: (1) Give all 20 values, some are missing. We can't check your answer without them. (2) Specifically, what intervals did you use? If they are of equal length, there is a possibility the distribution is too 'thin' in the right tail to give large enough expected counts $np_i$ in some of them for a good approximation of the chi-squared statistic to the chi-squared distribution. (3) Because you are estimating $\alpha$, you have df = n - 2, not df = n - 1. (4) "Totally different" from what? (5) Trivial: English terminology is 'point' estimator; and you have 'Hi-squared'.

Comment: You have to compute $\mathbb{P}(\chi²(n-2)>x)$ where $x$ is the value computed by formula 1.